How to mock an authentication decorator in pytest for a flask app?
I have a simple flask app for eg:
app.py


from flask import Flask
from auth import token_required

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return {"status":"active"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

and my auth.py is:
auth.py
import jwt
from functools import wraps
from datetime import datetime
from flask import request, jsonify

def verify_token(token1):
    try:
        token = token1.split(' ')[1]
        decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
        exp = datetime.fromtimestamp(decoded.get("exp"))
        now = datetime.now()
        print(f"the expiry time is {exp} and the current is {now}")

        if exp < now:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        return False
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        return False


def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):

        token = request.headers.get('Authorization')

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing'}), 401

        if not verify_token(token):
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid or expired'}), 401

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated

and my pytest file is like:
test_file.py
import pytest
from app import app as flask_app
from unittest.mock import patch
from auth import token_required, verify_token
from functools import wraps

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    yield flask_app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_home_endpoint(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json == {"status": "Active"}


I want to mock this decorator for this api, how to do that?
I tried to mock the decorator by
import pytest
from app import app as flask_app
from unittest.mock import patch
from auth import token_required, verify_token
from functools import wraps

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    yield flask_app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

@patch('auth.token_required')
def test_home_endpoint(mock_token_required,client):
    mock_token_required.return_value=True
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json == {"status": "Active"}


but getting error like :
mock_token_required = <MagicMock name='token_required' id='1396837709200'>, client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'app'>>

@patch('auth.token_required')
def test_home_endpoint(mock_token_required, client):
    mock_token_required.return_value = True
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert 401 == 200

+ where 401 = <WrapperTestResponse streamed [401 UNAUTHORIZED]>.status_code

E

E

test_tests.py:26: AssertionError


also tried  changing the patch to 'auth.verify_token','app.token_required','app.verify_token' didn't worked

Is this the actual code? I see no use for the auth module in the app module whatsoever.

Not an answer to the literal question, but it might be in your interest to checkout https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ instead or at least peek into their test suite.
